# Fitnesse getting stuck while triggering it from java and selenium webdriver

Tags: freeze, fitnesse

We have a requirement where in we need to trigger fitnesse test from our java + webdriver code.
While doing so most of the the times fitnesse gets stuck/freeze and the fitnesse test never executes.
Has anyone faced this issue before?
Any solution would be highly appreciated

Comment: Can you elaborate how you trigger the fitnesse test. Can you trigger the fitnesse test manually?

Comment: I execute my fitnesse as webDriver.get("<fitnesse test url>") from my java code